# Already known weather for city should not repeat again

Tags: javascript, html, api

I'm trying my first weather api  APP. Here I'm trying to achive that if the city weather is already displayed , It should give the message "You already know the weather" . and should not repeat the weather

Here is my code. Anyone Please look at my code ...
What is the mistake I have been made.

```
<div class="main">
<div class="container">
<div class="search_por">
<h2>Weather </h2>
<div class="validate_msg color_white"></div>
<form>
<label for=""></label>
<input type="search" class="input_text" value="">
<button type="submit" id="sub_button" class="srh_button">Search</button>
</form>
<!-- <canvas id="icon1" width="150" height="75"></canvas> -->
<div class="dat_weather">
<ul id="list_it">
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>



var get_text=document.querySelector("form");
get_text.addEventListener("submit",e=>{
e.preventDefault();
var input_val=document.querySelector('input').value;
const apiKey="bc4c7e7826d2178054ee88fe00737da0";
const url=`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${input_val}&appid=${apiKey}&units=metric`;


fetch(url,{method:'GET'})
.then(response=>response.json())
.then(data=>{console.log(data)


const{main,sys,weather,wind}=data;

//icons-end  
 var error_ms=document.getElementsByClassName("validate_msg")[0];
    var iconcode = weather[0].icon;
 console.log(iconcode);
var li=document.createElement("Li");
var weatherinfo=`<div class="nameci font_40" data-name="${data.name},${sys.country}"><span>${data.name}</span><sup>${sys.country}</sup></div>
<div class="temp_ic">
<img class="weat_icon" src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${iconcode}.png">
<div class="deg">${Math.floor( main.temp )}<sup>o</sup></div>
</div>
<div class="clear">
<div>${weather[0].description}</div>
</div>

`;
li.innerHTML=weatherinfo;

var ulid=document.getElementById("list_it");

ulid.appendChild(li);


    
var city_name=data.name;    
console.log(skycons);
var listitems=document.querySelectorAll('#list_it');


  const listArray=Array.from(listitems);
 

  
  if(listArray.length>0)
  {
      
    var filtered_array=listArray.filter(el=>{
        
        let content="";
        if(input_val.includes(','))
        {
            
            
            
            if(input_val.split(',')[1].length>2)
            {
                alert("hving 2 commos");
                inputval=input_val.split(',')[0];
                
                content=el.querySelector(".nameci span").textContent.toLowerCase();
                
                //content=el.querySelector(".nameci").innerHTML.toLowerCase();
                //content=inputval.toLowerCase();
            

            }
            
            else
            {
                content=el.querySelector(".nameci").dataset.name.toLowerCase();
            }
            alert(filtered_array);
        }
        else
        {

            content=el.querySelector(".nameci span").textContent.toLowerCase();
        }
        console.log(inputval.toLowerCase());
        return inputval.toLowerCase();
        
        
    });
    if(filtered_array.length>0)
    {
        console.log(filtered_array.length);
     error_ms.innerHTML="You Already know the weather of this country....";
     get_text.reset();
     return;
    }
    
  }
 
})
  .catch((error)=>{
  error_ms.innerHTML="Please Enter a valid city Name";
  
  
  });
  
  
  var error_ms=document.getElementsByClassName("validate_msg")[0];
error_ms.innerHTML="";
//var get_text=document.querySelector("form");
get_text.reset();

});
```

My full code is here:
https://codepen.io/pavisaran/pen/wvJaqBg

Comment: You will do yourself many favors if you compel yourself to format your working code the way that Henry Ecker reformatted the code in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try keeping track of a list of displayed locations outside of the callback:

```js
var get_text = document.querySelector("form");
// Keep Track Of Displayed Cities Here Instead
let displayed = [];


get_text.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var input_val = document.querySelector('input').value;
    const apiKey = "bc4c7e7826d2178054ee88fe00737da0";
    const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${input_val}&appid=${apiKey}&units=metric`;

    fetch(url, {method: 'GET'})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            var error_ms = document.getElementsByClassName("validate_msg")[0];
            const {main, sys, weather, wind, name} = data;
            if (displayed.length > 0) {
                // Filter Displayed Based on Current vs name from data (response)
                const filtered_array = displayed.filter(el => el === name);
                if (filtered_array.length > 0) {
                    error_ms.innerHTML = "You Already know the weather of this country....";
                    get_text.reset();
                    return Promise.resolve();
                }

            }
            // Add City To Array of Displayed Cities
            displayed.push(name);

            // Do Rest of Code to Add New City
            var iconcode = weather[0].icon;
            var li = document.createElement("Li");
            var weatherinfo = `<div class="nameci font_40" data-name="${data.name},${sys.country}"><span>${data.name}</span><sup>${sys.country}</sup></div>
<div class="temp_ic">
<img class="weat_icon" src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${iconcode}.png">
<div class="deg">${Math.floor(main.temp)}<sup>o</sup></div>
</div>
<div class="clear">
<div>${weather[0].description}</div>
</div>

`;
            li.innerHTML = weatherinfo;
            var ulid = document.getElementById("list_it");
            ulid.appendChild(li);            
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            error_ms.innerHTML = "Please Enter a valid city Name";
        });
    var error_ms = document.getElementsByClassName("validate_msg")[0];
    error_ms.innerHTML = "";
    get_text.reset();
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Henry Ecker for your help . .It is working fine . and I am having one doubt what return Promise.resolve(); is doing here. it may be simple But As Im the bigeneer I want to know about it.

Comment: [Promise.resolve()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) is just an empty resolved promise. It's not doing anything, in this case, other than explicitly saying that the promise resolved normally. (This would mean any future thens would run). Alternatively, you could return [Promise.reject()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject) to move into a catch and handle the "you already know" message there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just check for the value which is coming from api whether it's present on your list or not. you can try this.

```
li.innerHTML=weatherinfo;

var ulid=document.getElementById("list_it");
var isPresent = false;
var items = ulid.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        if(items[i].innerHTML == li.innerHTML){
        alert("you already know the weather")
          isPresent = true;
   }
}
if(!isPresent){
   ulid.appendChild(li);
}
```